# Applications are being opened from sideways

Tags: iphone, motion

I have a dull issue with the iPhone 11 Pro.
All the apps are being opened from the right side(motion looks confusing, which bothers me a lot.)
I have tried force-restart, clearing RAM, and everything in settings, but nothing fixed the issue.
Phone is up to date and once I restart the device, issue comes back in a few days.

Has anyone had the same problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean when you pull the white bar up from the Dock to see running apps, the apps appear in a stack coming from the right, instead of the left?

Comment: No, I mean every time I open some app, it is not opening from the app icon position on the screen but from the sideways, looks very buggy

Comment: Could you upload a screenshot or [screen recording](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/guide/iphone/iphc872c0115/ios#iph2d8929ce1) to show us visually what's going on?